# Typescript project not recognizing custom local js function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a typescript project and I have written a custom java-script function to extend an existing external interface. It complies fine but at run time it throws error that findByText is not a function. Any help I can get to move forward is good.

The structure is as below -

**element-extend.js**

```
export function findByText (compareText) {    
let foundElement;
return this.each((element) => {
    element.getWebElement().getText().then((elementText) => {
        if (elementText.trim() === compareText) {
            foundElement = element;
        }
    });
}).then(() => foundElement);
```

}

**element-extend.d.ts**

```
 import { ElementArrayFinder, ElementFinder } from 'protractor/built/element';
 import { protractor } from 'protractor';

 declare module 'protractor/built/element' {
 export interface ElementArrayFinder {
  findByText(text: string) : ElementFinder;
  }
}
```

**Using it in some-file.ts**

```
useExtendedFunction(){      
  elementArray.findByText();
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"include": [      
  "helpers/jshelpers/element-extend.d.ts"
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a new function just by itself and want to use it as it is inside some class or object and probably on prototype level.

You can add a new function or override existing on a prototype level but I wouldn't recommend this.

It is much easier and safer to write a new function and pass an object as a parameter if necessary (in your case an array)

Also you don't have to write such code in javascript - typescript can do the trick - since there is no trick:)